# Identify SciFi story where Genetic Engineering created Fantasy monster like dragons

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic, genetic-engineering

Once again I am trying to find about a story I read decades ago in translation (I do not remember the title in Italian, either).
The main topic was a world where genetic engineering had starter producing "Fantasy" creatures (including satyrs, dragons) until for some reason tech-based civilization collapsed and the survivors were living in something that superficially resembles a Fantasy world.

If memory serves the book opens with a short scene where three "creatures" (including, but I am not sure anymore, a sort of werewolf) kill the family of the protagonist.

--- Some extra info as per requests in comments

a) It was probably a novel, definitely not a short story: it is difficult to say because it was published as part of a series that churned out lots of (translated) American and British works... but unfortunately in order to keep the throughput costant and make the page number more or less uniform, the editors often made extensive cuts to the original content (e.g. a couple of chapters completely removed from "The Shrinking Man"). For fellow Italians: Yes,  I am talking of [URANIA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urania_(magazine)).

b) As per point (a): it is difficult to know the publishing date of the originals - Urania started publishing in 1952 but they often reprinted their content so in 80s you could still get an "Issue" with a story that had been originally published 10 years before, and whose American first edition was maybe even older. I think that the original was maybe from the 70s (I doubt that Genetic Engineering was really a common trope in the 60s), but I really have no idea.

Comment: @user14111: I do not know "Pantropy" but on the other hand I do not consider myself an expert on SciFi, this is why I wrote "I doubt..." instead of "I am definitely sure that..." so thanks for the tip (and thanks also for the Urania listings, let me see if I can find it myself)

Comment: @user14111 - as far as I recall yes, it was probably in the 80s (I started reading Urania earlier than that: my father was also a fan of the genre so he would buy an Urania and then pass it to me if he considered the content suitable for my age, but I remember the specific story as something that I read comparatively "later" so I would start looking in the 1980-1985 range)

Comment: *Tempo di Mostri, Fiume di Dolore*. There was also a follow-up. One of the main characters was a "Neurumana" (whatever *that* was translated from) called Jasmine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it!

[World enough, and time](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0345327004) by James Kahn M.D. - I found it by perusing [Il Catalogo Vegetti](http://www.fantascienza.com/catalogo/collane/NILF70036/urania/) which lists each issue by year, and shows also a small pic of the cover, helping me to find it relatively quickly.

The Italian version was published on [December 1982](http://www.fantascienza.com/catalogo/volumi/NILF103645/tempo-di-mostri-fiume-di-dolore/) but the original book is from 1980 according to [Wikipedia's page on Kahn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Kahn).

Comment: And the next story in the series appeared in [*Urania* #948](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?383719) in July 1983.